# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory , adding 'r' prefix adds an extra slash which makes the directory don't exist

Tags: python, file, directory

I am using google colab, and this should be a simple problem but mine is so confusing. My program just couldn't detect directory. I have tried adding "r" prefix at the string, which doubled the slashes in the address- making the program unable to find where the folder is.

`TRAIN_DIR = r'C:\Users\Ash\OneDrive\Desktop\FYP\train'`

and the error result :

`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Ash\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\FYP\\train'`

Why double slashes all of the sudden :(

I tried using "/" , double slashes, it all don't work.

Comment: There is no 'double slash appearing', as you could see if you `print` your path. The first way you wrote it is correct, writing it with no `r'...'` and escaping the slashes (your 'double slashes' version, which is the default representation Python uses to show you such strings is also correct, and it would be equally correct to use single forward slashes `/` instead of backslashes. Your real problem is that the path doesn't exist on the machine on which you run your code.

Answer (score 0):

You said you were using Google colab: Colab can't access your files locally, so that's why you can't access your files. Try uploading them first and then point your directory to the online directory using relative pathing.